# How to add OpenSSL support for Android in QT windows

Tags: android, c++, qt

Hello i am trying to develop an app as a project for school. I ran to a problem. I was greeted with this.

[image]

After google searching here is what i found out. It would seem that google has stopped support of openSSL (the one responsible for httprequests) on android 7 + . So again i went to googling for solutions and stumbled into an official documentation form Qt on how to solve this.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html

Now again more problems, It would seem that for me to do it is to use a Linux based OS, which i dont have. So hence the Title. Is there anyway for me Using QT running on a WINDOWS operating system to add openSSL support to my android application?

Qt Creator v 4.6.1 and Qt v 5.11

Answer (score 0):

QT cames with OpenSSL. It should work perfectly. You may forget to add libs into apk. please refer [QT Doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/opensslsupport.html) for details.

Comment: The one in the docs involve using Linux commands, I'm running on windows. If you can show me which step i should only do for windows it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: from step 9 and onward is the only thing i think i can do, but i do not know the proper locations of this libraries

Comment: you can find neccesary libs inside QT folder. please look into where you installed QT

Comment: i do found one, libcrypto.dll.a . i could not find the libcrypto.so . Is this the same?

Comment: amazing! you also should find libssl.dll

Comment: I apologize if im ignorant on the subject matter, is this the only library that i would be needing ??

Comment: Qt only allows files with .so extention so those files cannot be added :(